# Is there a way to write bits of text to different files if different conditions are met?

Tags: python

I have this text which i will share a part from,

> ROMEO
>
> *But, soft! what light through yonder window breaks?
>   It is the east, and Juliet is the sun.*
>
> JULIET
>
> *Ay me!*
>
> ROMEO
>
> *She speaks:
>   O, speak again, bright angel! for thou art.*
>
> JULIET
>
> *O Romeo, Romeo! wherefore art thou Romeo?
>   Deny thy father and refuse thy name;*
>
> ROMEO
>
> *Shall I hear more, or shall I speak at this?.*

I want to write a loop that looks for the name in the line and saves the contents after it to a specific file, in this case if "ROMEO" is the word found every line after it will be saved to "Romeo.txt" until the word "JULIET" is found then all content is saved to "Juliet.txt". I tried coding it myself with an amalgamation of loops and if statements but it got me to nowhere. 
handle = open("romeo-full.txt")
skipper = "ROMEO"

```
handle = open("romeo-full.txt")
skipper = "ROMEO"

for line in handle:
    line = line.strip()     
    while skipper == "ROMEO":
        print(line) #This would be the write to file code
        if line.startswith("ROMEO"):
            skipper = "JULIET"
            break
        else:
            continue

    while skipper == "JULIET":
        print(line) #This would be the write to file code
        if line.startswith("ROMEO"):
            skipper = "ROMEO"
            break
        else:
            continue
```

The output is basically "ROMEO" lines looping, which i understood it's coming from the while loop going through the first line forever, but i couldn't figure a way out closer to what i want than this.

Comment: Sure, just open two more files and decide which one two write into. Files are just objects, assigned to a variable.

Comment: For small to medium sized blocks of text you can also accumulate the fragments into string buffers, then do one write per buffer once all of the input has been read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to avoid the duplicated code will be to use the headers in the main file as "choosers" for the what file to write to. Something like:

```py
with open("romeo-full.txt") as handle, \
     open("romeo.txt", 'w') as r_f, \
     open("juliet.txt", 'w') as j_f:

    file_chooser = {"ROMEO": r_f,
                    "JULIET": j_f}

    for line in handle:
        try:
            cur_file = file_chooser[line.strip()]
        except KeyError:     
            cur_file.write(line)
```

The purpose of the `try/except` block is to change the `cur_file` only when we encounter one of the headings (and then skip it).

---

One way to avoid that is to use dict's [`get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method with `cur_file` as the default (so it changes only on headers):

```py
with open("romeo-full.txt") as handle, \
     open("romeo.txt", 'w') as r_f, \
     open("juliet.txt", 'w') as j_f:

    file_chooser = {"ROMEO": r_f,
                    "JULIET": j_f}
    cur_file = r_f
    for line in handle:
        cur_file = file_chooser.get(line.strip(), cur_file)

        cur_file.write(line)
```

The downside here is that the headers will also be written each time to the files.

Comment: It works, thank you. I noticed that removing the pass statement and putting the last line inside the except statement made no difference, could you explain why is that?

Comment: Well that's because If we encounter a headline, we skip the loop; and if not we pass the exception and reach that line anyway. I didn't notice that, and actually the continue is also not necessary in that case! will update now. Good catch! I completely missed that

Answer (score 0):

You can write to multiple files like so:

```
with open('example1.txt', 'w') as file_1 \
        , open('example2.txt', 'w') as file_2 \
        , open('example3.txt', 'w') as file_3 \
        , open("romeo-full.txt", 'r') as handle:
    for line in handle:
        if condition_1:
            file_1.write(line)
        elif condition_2:
            file_2.write(line)
        elif condition_3:
            file_3.write(line)
```

The reason you should always use `with` instead of `open` and `close` is because if for some reason you don't close (like the program crashing or you forgetting to add it), the file will not be closed, taking up space. I've seen it happen that files that are frequently opened and not closed cause servers to crash!